# AutoHotKey script to copy text from a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey, google-chrome-extensions

I am using Windows 10.

I want to assign a hotkey to automatically copy and paste text from a chrome extension's default popup window (the one you can access for example by left clicking on an extension in the top right of chrome).

In particular, I am using the [Authenticator](https://github.com/Authenticator-Extension/Authenticator) extension, and I want to assign a hotkey to copy the contents of `<div class="code">`.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: FWIW, I can't find anything from that menu being exposed in either AU3_Spy or AHKWindowInfo. It may not be possible to directly capture the contents.

Comment: @EngineerToast thanks, that's helpful info. Maybe I could somehow get ahk to switch to an open chrome window, open the extension and somehow click in the top 1/3 (which causes the extension itself to place the contents in the clipboard)?